# Set ClassPath for SBT outside of build.sbt/build.scala

Tags: log4j, classpath, sbt, slf4j

I am making a basic program that uses SLF4J. The main point of using SLF4J is to manually specify the .jar files for the logging backend you are using (along with the properties files of that logger) using the java classpath. This means the .jar related to the slf4j (outside of the base slf4j) are not specified inside your SBT project as dependencies.

The problem is that when you do a run command in sbt, it sets the classpath to `/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.11.3-2/libexec/sbt-launch.jar` (I have sbt installed through homebrew on a mac)

My question is, is there a way to set classpath directory for SBT (when using run on a scala application) to a specific directory without having modify the actual SBT project (maybe with something like a properties file?) when I use the sbt command run?. Currently in order to test my application with logging, I have to make a min.jar using proguard plugin for SBT and manually run a command like this (which is incredibly tedious)

```
java -Djava.ext.dirs=<some_path> -Dlog4j.configuration=<some_path> -jar scheduler_2.9.1-1.0.min.jar
```

There isn't a problem with this, and its how the app is meant to be used in production. However I wan't to test my app (to see if logging works) when using the sbt run command, and I don't know how I can configure SBT to do this without altering the build.sbt/Build.scala file (which would obviously cause issues when using it in production)

Note that the `-Dlog4j.configuration` is not required if I can specify the classpath as I want. I already tried putting `-DJava.ext.dirs=<some_path>` on the command that launches sbt, but unsurprisingly it has no effect on the run command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a good solution for you, but you could add `user.sbt` in the working directory with the added `fullClasspath in Runtime` setting.